# How avoid the multiple render with JEST?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have two `'test'`, and in both, I'm using the same component.

How to avoid this?
Exist one way of reutilized for this?

```
describe('AppbarGlobal [GLOBAL COMPONENT]', () => {
    test('Should be have the [TEXTS]', async () => {
        render(<AppbarGlobal />);
        expect(screen.getByText(/dApp - Superior Electoral Court/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
    });

    test('Should be have the [COMPONENTS]', async () => {
        render(<AppbarGlobal />);

        const logotype = screen.getByRole('img');
        const button = screen.getByText(/Connect Wallet/i);

        expect(logotype).toBeInTheDocument();
        expect(button).toBeInTheDocument();
    });

    test('Should be working the Connect Wallet [BUTTON]', async () => {
        render(<AppbarGlobal />);
        expect(fireEvent.click(screen.getByText(/Connect Wallet/i))).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Comment: You can use a combination of multiple `expect` statements and `const { rerender } = render(<AppbarGlobal />)` to rerender your component in the same `test`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid writing out every `render()` call by using `beforeEach`:

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  render(<AppbarGlobal />);
});
```

You shouldn't, however, use the same rendered instance across different tests.

Comment: Forbidden usage of `render` within testing framework `beforeEach` setupeslinttesting-library/no-render-in-setup

Comment: @THIAGODEBONIS Then leave your code as is. It is good and clear.